# Flutter handle TextField submitted

Tags: flutter

I have a text field that I search with.
I use the follwing codes:

```
TextField(
  controller: searchController,
  maxLines: 1,
  autofocus: true,
  onSubmitted: _search(),
),
```

```
_search(){
    print('here');
  }
```

But in output `_serach` method is called in a infinite loop when I submit text field. I want to call `_search` method one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all `onSubmitted` must be `void Function (String?)`, while you passing `void Function()`. Try Something like this, it should work. At least it works for me:

```
TextField(
    controller: _controller,
    onSubmitted: (String value) async {
        await _performSearch(value);
    },
),
```

Comment: thank, this worked for me